# Time in segmented fit

Tags: r, time

I'm trying to do a segmented fit in r but my psi is equal to time. Someone knows how to convert this in order to work ?

```
fit <- lm(x ~ time, data=y)
sf <- segmented(fit, seg.Z=~time, psi=c("07:08:00", "10:00:00", "18:30:00"),
                npsi=3)
```

> dput(head(y, 30))

structure(list(cultivar = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Kluai Tiparot",
"Red Dacca", "Simili Radjah"), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(1642905000,
1642905900, 1642906800, 1642907700, 1642908600, 1642909500, 1642910400,
1642911300, 1642912200, 1642913100, 1642914000, 1642914900, 1642915800,
1642916700, 1642917600, 1642918500, 1642919400, 1642920300, 1642921200,
1642922100, 1642923000, 1642923900, 1642924800, 1642925700, 1642926600,
1642927500, 1642928400, 1642929300, 1642930200, 1642931100), class = c("POSIXct",
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), cum_trans_per_day = c(0.42133699633689,
0.753397435897114, 0.870499084248763, 0.784604918889532, 1.24111721611712,
1.35111721611713, 1.5536577708, 1.70326007325968, 2.00980769230716,
2.23016483516426, 2.45278388278325, 2.57629578754518, 2.81504578754505,
3.07837912087825, 3.32534340659254, 3.63028388278315, 3.85343864468791,
4.61695054944983, 5.15314102564014, 6.0794505494498, 7.09611721611645,
7.87837912087844, 8.93611721611637, 10.5801648351643, 12.1977838827831,
14.0954029304021, 16.5244505494499, 19.2929624542116, 21.5838553113545,
24.1336172161166)), row.names = c(1L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 13L, 16L,
19L, 22L, 25L, 28L, 31L, 34L, 37L, 40L, 43L, 46L, 49L, 52L, 55L,
58L, 61L, 64L, 67L, 70L, 73L, 76L, 79L, 82L, 85L, 88L), class = "data.frame")

time

[1] "2022-01-23 03:30:00 CET" "2022-01-23 03:45:00 CET" "2022-01-23 04:00:00 CET" "2022-01-23 04:15:00 CET"
[5] "2022-01-23 04:30:00 CET" "2022-01-23 04:45:00 CET" "2022-01-23 05:00:00 CET" "2022-01-23 05:15:00 CET"
[9] "2022-01-23 05:30:00 CET" "2022-01-23 05:45:00 CET" "2022-01-23 06:00:00 CET" "2022-01-23 06:15:00 CET"
[13] "2022-01-23 06:30:00 CET" "2022-01-23 06:45:00 CET" "2022-01-23 07:00:00 CET" "2022-01-23 07:15:00 CET"
[17] "2022-01-23 07:30:00 CET" "2022-01-23 07:45:00 CET" "2022-01-23 08:00:00 CET" "2022-01-23 08:15:00 CET"
[21] "2022-01-23 08:30:00 CET" "2022-01-23 08:45:00 CET" "2022-01-23 09:00:00 CET" "2022-01-23 09:15:00 CET"
[25] "2022-01-23 09:30:00 CET" "2022-01-23 09:45:00 CET" "2022-01-23 10:00:00 CET" "2022-01-23 10:15:00 CET"
[29] "2022-01-23 10:30:00 CET" "2022-01-23 10:45:00 CET" "2022-01-23 11:00:00 CET" "2022-01-23 11:15:00 CET"
[33] "2022-01-23 11:30:00 CET" "2022-01-23 11:45:00 CET" "2022-01-23 12:00:00 CET" "2022-01-23 12:15:00 CET"
[37] "2022-01-23 12:30:00 CET" "2022-01-23 12:45:00 CET" "2022-01-23 13:00:00 CET" "2022-01-23 13:15:00 CET"
[41] "2022-01-23 13:30:00 CET" "2022-01-23 13:45:00 CET" "2022-01-23 14:00:00 CET" "2022-01-23 14:15:00 CET"
[45] "2022-01-23 14:30:00 CET" "2022-01-23 14:45:00 CET" "2022-01-23 15:00:00 CET" "2022-01-23 15:15:00 CET"
[49] "2022-01-23 15:30:00 CET" "2022-01-23 15:45:00 CET" "2022-01-23 16:00:00 CET" "2022-01-23 16:15:00 CET"
[53] "2022-01-23 16:30:00 CET" "2022-01-23 16:45:00 CET" "2022-01-23 17:00:00 CET" "2022-01-23 17:15:00 CET"
[57] "2022-01-23 17:30:00 CET" "2022-01-23 17:45:00 CET" "2022-01-23 18:00:00 CET" "2022-01-23 18:15:00 CET"
[61] "2022-01-23 18:30:00 CET" "2022-01-23 18:45:00 CET" "2022-01-23 19:00:00 CET" "2022-01-23 19:15:00 CET"
[65] "2022-01-23 19:30:00 CET" "2022-01-23 19:45:00 CET" "2022-01-23 20:00:00 CET" "2022-01-23 20:15:00 CET"
[69] "2022-01-23 20:30:00 CET" "2022-01-23 20:45:00 CET" "2022-01-23 21:00:00 CET" "2022-01-23 21:15:00 CET"
[73] "2022-01-23 21:30:00 CET" "2022-01-23 21:45:00 CET" "2022-01-23 22:00:00 CET" "2022-01-23 22:15:00 CET"
[77] "2022-01-23 22:30:00 CET" "2022-01-23 22:45:00 CET" "2022-01-23 23:00:00 CET" "2022-01-23 23:15:00 CET"
[81] "2022-01-23 23:30:00 CET" "2022-01-23 23:45:00 CET"

x

[1]   0.4213370   0.7533974   0.8704991   0.7846049   1.2411172   1.3511172   1.5536578   1.7032601   2.0098077   2.2301648
[11]   2.4527839   2.5762958   2.8150458   3.0783791   3.3253434   3.6302839   3.8534386   4.6169505   5.1531410   6.0794505
[21]   7.0961172   7.8783791   8.9361172  10.5801648  12.1977839  14.0954029  16.5244505  19.2929625  21.5838553  24.1336172
[31]  26.9055815  29.0542125  31.5219505  34.2994505  36.4279625  38.9243315  41.5325458  44.1854625  46.8136172  49.7436172
[41]  52.9102839  56.2320696  59.1180220  61.6592125  64.4617125  67.2611172  70.0236172  72.9694505  75.6087363  78.1966529
[51]  80.4968315  82.8461172  85.3511172  87.5561172  90.0111172  92.0424267  94.0649267  95.8518315  97.5669505  99.1602839
[61] 100.4852839 101.8528434 103.0435577 105.3314204 104.8389744 105.2939744 105.6339744 106.0373077 106.4035577 106.5930815
[71] 107.0848672 107.4439744 108.0531410 108.4981410 110.5586185 109.2249267 109.6979029 109.9137363 110.3487363 110.6279029
[81] 110.8437363 111.0476053

Comment: Maybe with package `chron`. Try `psi <- chron::chron(times. = c("07:08:00", "10:00:00", "18:30:00"))` and then `segmented(fit, seg.Z=~time, psi=psi, npsi=3)`.

Comment: Also, can you post data? Please post the output of `dput(head(y, 30))`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.